# Many worlds interpretation of quantamechanics vs eternal information

Tags: cosmology, quantum-interpretations, cosmological-inflation

Whats the main difference between the theory of [many worlds interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation) in quantum mechanics and the theory of [eternal inflation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_inflation) or are they the same in regard of their vision to the multiverse ?

Comment: The articles were confusing to me. Is the many worlds interpretation that the universe bifurcate into multiple universes when something is observed? Is  eternal inflation that far enough away there are other sources/big bangs with their own physical laws?

Comment: So, Ammar, those two interpretations, or reasons for a MWI are different. One says every quantum possibility generates another universe, the other says eternal inflation creates new universes all the time. Different reasons for a multiverse. @Emil's comment embodies the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

No they are not the same in terms of their interpretation of the multiverse.

The primary difference between the two would be; the many world's interpretation is purely quantum mechanical, where each new universe depends on the past events. More specifically, an event happens in the past, and multiple new universes will branch off, each containing a different result for that one event. Then of course you have probability amplitudes and quantum mechanical observation laws which dictate the wavefunction collapse into one of these universes.

On the other hand you have the type of multiverse described by the eternal inflation theory, this is purely relativistic. New universes are created randomly relating to inflation, these alternate universes within the great multiverse may not have the same physical laws as our own universe- in this interpretation, our universe, their universe, is just a bubble, and these bubbles can merge and interact.

So in conclusion, the main difference is that eternal inflation is relativistic and treats universes like bubbles that are randomly created and can interact with each other. Whereas the many world's interpretation is quantum mechanical, and alternate universes are branches whose creation and existence depends on a QM event and observation of that event.